# Similar Triangle and Quad

Tags: geometry

In Triangle RST, a line parallel to segment ST intersects segments RS and RT at points A and B, respectively. If the area of triangle RST is 1024 and the area of the quad, SABT, is 240, find the value of AB:ST.

Note: I have no idea what to do with this problem. I don't know anything in Algebra 2 and beyond, so keep that in mind when trying to explain, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The triangles $\triangle RST$ and $\triangle RAB$ are similar, i.e. $\triangle RST$ is *proportional* to $\triangle RAB$

Suppose that the similarity factor is $k$. Thus $$\frac{\text{Area}_{\triangle RST}}{\text{Area}_{\triangle RAB}}=\frac{\text{Area}_{\triangle RAB}+\text{Area}_{SABT}}{\text{Area}_{\triangle RAB}}=1+\frac{\text{Area}_{SABT}}{\triangle RST-\text{Area}_{SABT}}=1+\frac{240}{786}=k^2$$ And due to the similarity, we know that $$\frac{ST}{AB}=k$$ Can you end it now?